# excel vba loop through worksheets fails

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why this function doesn't loop through the worksheets , what am I  missing ?

I've gone through Almost every resource I can find both on stack overflow and Google but could not find an answer that I could implement.

I've tried looping through worksheet numbers however that didn't work so I am now attempting to loop through worksheet names. This also does not work.

I'm pretty sure it's a small error but I could not find the cause after days of searching.

```
Sub CreateUniquesList()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer 'number of WorkSheets
    Dim Sheet As Integer 'WorkSheet number
    Dim Uniques() As String 'Array of all unique references
    Dim UniquesLength As Integer
    Dim size As Integer 'number of items to add to Uniques
    Dim Row As Integer 'row number
    Dim Column As Variant 'column number
    Dim Columns As Variant
    Dim blanks
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim wks As Variant, wksNames() As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ReDim wksNames(WS_Count - 1)
    i = 0
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        wksNames(i) = wks.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Columns = Array(3, 4, 8, 11, 12, 17, 18)
    ReDim Uniques(0)
    Uniques(0) = "remove this item"
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'    For Sheet = 1 To WS_Count
    For Each wks In wksNames
        For Each Column In Columns
'            LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row
'            size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(Sheet).Columns(Column)) - 1
            LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks).Cells(Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row
            size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(wks).Columns(Column)) - 1
            UniquesLength = UBound(Uniques) - LBound(Uniques) + 1
            ReDim Preserve Uniques(UniquesLength + size - 1)
            blanks = 0
            i = 1
            For Row = LastRow To 2 Step -1
                If Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "" Then
                    Uniques(UniquesLength + i - 1 - blanks) = Cells(Row, Column).Value
                Else
                    blanks = blanks + 1
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next Row
        Next Column
    Next wks
'    Next Sheet

    'remove first unique element
    For i = 1 To UBound(Uniques)
        Uniques(i - 1) = Uniques(i)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Uniques(UBound(Uniques) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line do you have the error? and what kind of error is it?

Comment: Where is the code stopping? What is the error you're seeing? Or is it just not doing what you'd expect? Give us more information.

Comment: change this `For Each wks In wksNames` to `For Each wks In Worksheets`

Comment: So the Line that wont work is this one: `size=WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(wks).Columns(Column)) -1`  What are you trying to look for? your var "size" has a negative value, this leads into trying to define an array with a negative length. in this line: `ReDim Preserve Uniques(UniquesLength + size - 1)` you could just take out the "-1" but i dont know what you want to do

Comment: All this seems to do is load non-blank values into an array.  It doesn't seem to perform any kind of check to verify that each value being loaded is unique.  At the end of the code, the array isn't actually used for anything (not fed into another function/macro, not output to a sheet, nothing).  What is the purpose of this code??

Comment: basslo, CLR - I don't have an error in the code, the code runs in its entirety. The problem is that instead of going through all of the sheets, the code runs on the first sheet the number of times equivalent to the number of sheets.

UGP - I don't have a problem with the line you mentioned. The reason is because I have a header at the top of each column in a row 1. Therefore, I always remove one integer. Further, the array starts at 0.

tigeravatar - your correct, the code does nothing right now. This is only the beginning. Eventually there will be checks and outputs to a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the code and have rewritten a fair portion of it as I don't think a lot of it was necessary (probably leftover from your attempts to make things work).  Try this, and if you don't understand any of it, post a comment and I'll explain further.

```
Sub CreateUniquesList()

    Dim Uniques() As String 'Array of all unique references
    Dim Row As Integer 'row number
    Dim Column As Variant 'column number
    Dim Columns As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Columns = Array(3, 4, 8, 11, 12, 17, 18)
    ReDim Uniques(0)

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Column In Columns
            LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row
            For Row = LastRow To 2 Step -1
                If wks.Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "" Then
                    Uniques(UBound(Uniques)) = wks.Cells(Row, Column).Value ' set the last element of the array to the value
                    ReDim Preserve Uniques(UBound(Uniques)+1)   ' increment the size of the array
                End If
            Next Row
        Next Column
    Next wks

    ' lose the last element of the array as it's one larger than it needs to be
    ReDim Preserve Uniques(UBound(Uniques) - 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly.
If I would like to prompt a user to select a certain sheet to run this code, instead of cycling through all of the worksheets, how can I do that?
Specifically, I would like to display a drop-down menu containing all of the sheet names and have the user select the desired sheet name. I have no experience with writing code that prompts user input. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @EitanWaks You should really raise a new question on that but in simple terms, to give you an idea where to start:  If you want to use a dropdown you should create a `UserForm` on which to place it, and populate it with the names of the sheets.  Then you can use the dropdown's `Selection` event to trigger a call to the code, and pass it the name of the worksheet.  Modify the function to accept the name and set a reference to the relevant worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 
 '    For Sheet = 1 To WS_Count
 For Each wks In Worksheets
 For Each Column In Columns
 'LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Cells(Rows.Count,column).End(xlUp).Row
 'size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(Sheet).Columns(Column)) - 1
 LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wks.Name).Cells(Rows.Count,Column).End(xlUp).Row
 size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(wks.Name).Columns(Column)) - 1
 UniquesLength = UBound(Uniques) - LBound(Uniques) + 1
 ReDim Preserve Uniques(UniquesLength + size - 1)
 blanks = 0
 i = 1
 For Row = LastRow To 2 Step -1
 If Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "" Then
 Uniques(UniquesLength + i - 1 - blanks) = Cells(Row, Column).Value
 Else
 blanks = blanks + 1
 End If
 i = i + 1
 Next Row
 Next Column
 Next wks
```